# Nginx's config file nginx.conf is loaded statically or dynamically?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Will nginx loads its nginx.conf file statically? Is there a way to change the content of file later and can it be dynamically updated? If yes, how it can be done?

Comment: Simple: No.   Yes.   Yes.

Comment: Can you explain your answer to Yes. how it can be done without reloading.I am new to nginx, so please excuse me if i am missing something obvious.

Comment: I consider the reload to be "dynamic", partly because it does not interrupt service. Unit by nginx could be another option, but you should describe your scenario in more detail

Answer (score 2):

The configuration file will be loaded when nginx starts, changes done afterwards will not be loaded until you restart nginx or tell it to re-read it's configuration files.

```
# Restarts nginx using systemd (which will reload the configuration)    
systemctl restart nginx

# Reload configuration without shutting down nginx
nginx -s reload
# or with systemd
systemctl reload nginx

# Test configuration without loading it
nginx -t
```

You can find more information about this in the [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#control).